# Changing defaults of UISlider in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uislider

So currently I am tinkering with swift and iOS 8, I have dragged a UISlider onto my view and created an Outlet for it

```
@IBOutlet weak var homePurchase: UISlider!
```

As well as a function to run when it is changed

```
@IBAction func homePurchaseChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    println(Int(homePurchase.value))
}
```

My question is how do I change the default values of the UISlider so that instead of it being a range of 0 - 1, I want it to be 20,000 to 500,000

I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that can be easily answered by looking at the documentation which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISlider/value). You set the minimum and maximum values of the slider like so:

```
    homePurchase.minimumValue = 20000
    homePurchase.maximumValue = 500000
```

Comment: I did this and I get an error that states expected declaration

Comment: You have to put it in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Ah, yeah, you got it. Thanks a lot, kind of a noob question but I am a noob with this.